# Magento: Add image between top navigation (or header) and search form

Tags: image, magento, header, navigation

how can I add an image with js code and external link in my top navigation. It should be placed between the menu links and search form.

maybe it has to be adapted in the header. I don`t know it also how to do it there.

here u can see a screenshot of the current site. 
[Screenshot](http://www.traditionalgermangoods.com/top_naviation.jpg)

```
<?php if ($customlogo['logo_status'] == 0): ?>
                <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
                <?php else:?>
                <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $customlogo['logo_alt']; ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $customlogo['logo_alt']; ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $mediaurl.$customlogo['logo']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $customlogo['logo_alt']; ?>" /></a></h1>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="quick-access">
                <div class="menu-button"></div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

GUESS, it must placed between these two code snippets... but how?

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question really. Replace GUESS, it must be placed... with image tag and use css to style accordingly. Alternatively, you can create a custom block and phtml file, add an instance of your block to page.xml layout file and then in the template as above you could use $this->getChildHtml('myCustomBlock'), but for the sake of a single image I would use the first image or use CSS background styles if that's what's it for. You could also insert the image in the phtml file for topMenu or topSearch. I suggest you read the design guide http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/themes-and-design/